# Shiny: Input selection through conditional panels is overruled

Tags: shiny

I would like to switch my input field from checkboxes to radio buttons, depending on which graph type is chosen. The input variables are equal in either case, but some graphs allow for multiple inputs and some not. The UI works like expected, but the radio buttons do not affect the input variable sent to server.R, while the checkboxes keep being effective even if the graph type is selected which requires radio button input. What am I missing?

```
conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.graphtype != 'Graph Type 2'",
          checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Select variables:",
                            c("variable1","variable2","variable3")
                            )
         ),
conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.graphtype == 'Graph Type 2'",
           radioButtons("variable", "Select variable:",
                       c("variable1","variable2","variable3")
                       )
         )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that both  the radio buttons and the checkboxes are using the same ID. Both of them are using id `variable`. You can't have that. In HTML, every element must have a unique ID. Since you're defining the checkboxes first, they get to keep the ID and are accessible, but the radio buttons are inaccessible because their id is already taken.  I think if you switch the position of the two conditions then the radio buttons will work instead of the checkboxes, if that's the case then that'll prove me right.

Anyway, even if this isn't the only problem (but I'm pretty sure it is), it's definitely a problem that you need to fix. The two inputs must have different IDs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I had that in mind as a workaround, so it is good to have confirmed that the first option really is not going to work.